# C# DatagridView fill with class SingleResponsibility

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, class, datagridview

Hi StackOverflow members, I decided to build a library project to improve myself.
I created a class to code Book Operations but i couldn't find out how to fill datagrid via class method.
When i text this method into a button action it didn't work. I found out a solution to make it happen. And here's some code from my BookOperation class;

```
public void GetBookByName(Yönetici f1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kitaplar where Kitap_Adi like '%" + f1.textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'", conn); 
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
    public void GetBookByAuthor(Yönetici f1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from kitaplar where Yazar like '%" + f1.textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();

    }
    public void GetBookByGenre(Yönetici f1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from kitaplar where Tür like '%" + f1.textBox1.Text.Trim() + "%'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Yönetici is the name of my application screen of book operations.
In the button action, it includes;

```
Kitap_islemleri ki = new Kitap_islemleri();
ki.GetBookByName(this);
```

is it okay for single responsibility or is there any different way? Can you please help me?
That's kind of weird using somemethod(this), is it wrong or good for a start? what do you think. How can i get data without using (this)? If there's a way, can you hit it?

Comment: Your methods should return a DataTable, not receive a Form reference and set a UI Control (your methods should know nothing about UI components). It's in the Form side that you use the data get back for whatever purpose. Side note: you are storing a Connection object (you should create one and dispose of it in-place) and not disposing of the SqlDataAdapter, which can open a connection on its own, btw.

Comment: Can you show an example for this?

Comment: About how to write `public DataTable GetBookByName() {  }` and `f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = GetBookByName();` instead of `public void GetBookByName(Yönetici f1)`? BTW2, you need just one method that returns a DataTable with your books. Filter and Sort can be applied dynamically on the UI side (in relation to the UI requirements), using the DataTable.defaultView or a BindingSource.

Comment: I changed it GetBookByName(string text,DataGridView dgv) i guess it's been solved

Comment: Nope. Don't pass **any** UI element to those methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to change your method parameters and return type with what you need. It seems your queries need just 1 criteria.

```
public DataTable GetBookByName(string bookName)
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kitaplar where Kitap_Adi like '%" + bookName.Trim() + "%'", conn); 
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

So you won't need all the Yonetici page on your data access layer and with returned DataTable, you can bind it to your gridview on presentation layer.

```
var bookName = f1.textBox1.Text;
f1.dataGridView1.DataSource = ki.GetBookByName(bookname);
```

Part 2

```
public DataTable GetBooks(string filter, string criteria)
{
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Kitaplar where " + filter + " like '%" + criteria.Trim() + "%'", conn); 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
conn.Close();
return dt;
}
```

Usage

```
GetBooks("Kitap_Adi", "name");
GetBooks("Yazar", "author");
GetBooks("Tür", "kind")
```

Comment: Nerden baksan kral hareket aga
That's what i was looking for.. thanks!

Comment: As long as you ask questions in accordance with the rules, everyone in the community will be happy to help you. Rica ederim :)

Comment: So what about make it search more than one? I mean GetBookBy(string bookname,string by) and sqlcommand is Select * from Kitaplar where "+by+" like ....?
Is it okay for Single Responsibility? I think it has to be.

Comment: The code is already single responsible. It has no responsibility other than to fetching data. With that you said, you can avoid from code duplication. I updated code with "part2" for demonstration, please check and sure you should always apply your code this kind of improvements.

Comment: Thank you so soo much, i've been looking for that for 3-4 days and then one who is a hero comes up and answers what you wanna find out. Not all heroes wear capes